# How to import lodash single function and use on Vue.js template?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, lodash

I tried to import a single Lodash function inside my Vue.js component, like this:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <span v-if="!isEmpty(example)">{{example}}</span>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty"

export default {
    data () {
        return { example: "Some text" }
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I use it inside the template it gives this error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "isEmpty" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I have this lodash entry in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your options are either to pass the function through `data`:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return { 
            isEmpty: isEmpty,
            example: "Some text",
        }
    }
}
```

or to make a computed property:

```
<span v-if="!exampleTextEmpty">{{example}}</span>

// ...

export default {
    data () {
        return { example: "Some text" }
    },
    computed: {
        exampleTextEmpty() {
            return isEmpty(this.example);
        }
    }
}
```